# How to prevent refresh database with realm.io when I rebuild ios simulator?

Tags: ios, realm

In my code, I certanly saved my realm objects, and I confirm realm database has 1 count.
but I build and rerun from xcode, my realm database is refreshed and database has 0 count.
Why realm database is cleared? and How do I prevent refreshing?
I think this is not code problem but settings...

Additionally, "/tmp/hogehogerealm2.realm" file has no change when I rebuild.

```
// some service model
func createRealm() {
    let realm = RLMRealm(path:"/tmp/hogehogerealm2.realm")

    let storedCredential = FMUserCredential.allObjects()
    if (storedCredential != nil && storedCredential.count >= 1) {
        realm.beginWriteTransaction()
        realm.deleteObjects(storedCredential)
        realm.commitWriteTransaction()
    }

    var credential = FMUserCredential()
    if let atoken = userCredential.token {
        credential.accessToken = atoken
    }
    if let rtoken = userCredential.refreshToken {
        credential.refreshToken = rtoken
    }

    realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    realm.addObject(credential)
    realm.commitWriteTransaction()

    FMUserCredential.allObjects().count // 1
}
-----------------------------
// model of FMUserCredential

import Foundation

class FMUserCredential: RLMObject {
    dynamic var accessToken = ""
    dynamic var refreshToken = ""
    class func find() -> FMUserCredential? {
        println("FMUserCredential.allObjects().count")
        println(FMUserCredential.allObjects().count)
        if (FMUserCredential.allObjects().count >= 1) {
            return FMUserCredential.allObjects().firstObject() as FMUserCredential?
        }
        return nil
    }
}
----------------------------- 
func isUserLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    if (FMUserCredential.find() == nil) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Does everything work if you don't use a path inside `/tmp`, since `/tmp` is periodically cleaned by the OS?

Comment: thanks segiddins. but it's not problem because there are files, hogehogerealm2.realm and hogehogerealm2.lock. Additionally, I used realm browser and there are some values before re run, but I rerun and get record count is zero. It's wered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by myself.
This is problem has occured by defaultRealm().
I assume defaultRealm is refreshed rerun.

So I changed code like below.

```
import Foundation

class FMUserCredential: RLMObject {
    dynamic var accessToken = ""
    dynamic var refreshToken = ""

    class func realm() -> RLMRealm {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let realmPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm")
        let realm = RLMRealm(path:realmPath, readOnly:false, error:nil)
        return realm
    }

    class func findAll() -> RLMResults {
        return FMUserCredential.allObjectsInRealm(realm())
    }
    class func find() -> FMUserCredential? {
        if (findAll().count >= 1) {
            return findAll().firstObject() as FMUserCredential?
        }
        return nil
    }

}

////////////////////////////////////

// client code
let storedCredential = FMUserCredential.findAll()
if (storedCredential.count >= 1) {
    realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    realm.deleteObjects(storedCredential)
    realm.commitWriteTransaction()
}
```